# Show uniform convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k e^{-kx}$ where $x \in [0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I want to show uniform convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k e^{-kx}$ where $x \in [0,\infty)$. I am not sure how to demonstrate this since any avenues I have pursued have not worked. Does the Weierstrass M-test work for this, or should I be using something else?

I know the M-test works for just the $e^{-kx}$ portion, but I can't figure out how this will work for the whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to proceed by showing the function $f(x) = x^k*e^{-kx}$ is bounded. This is the [M-test for uniform continuity](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/uniform-convergence-of-series).

So, we want to show there exists $M>0$ such that $|x^k*e^{-kx}| < M$ for all $x \in [0, \infty]$ and all $k \in [1, \infty]$. For finite $x$, this seems plausible. Let's first consider what happens as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}x^k*e^{-kx} $ = $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^k}{e^{kx}}$.

Now we can use L'Hopital's rule $k$ times, and we're left with $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{e^{x}} = 0$.

It ended up not even mattering what happened to $k$ in that limit.

What matters is the function values become very small as x becomes very large, so even as we sum k to infinity, we're ultimately shrinking our finite sums down, so the infinite sum converges.

Comment: Your application of the $M$-test is incorrect. In order to correctly apply this test, what you need to do is to find a sequence $(M_k)$ of real numbers such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} M_k<\infty$, and such that for all $x \geq 0$ and $k \in \Bbb N$ we have that $x^ke^{-kx} \leq M_k$. This is not what you have shown.

Comment: So I guess I could proceed a little differently. 

It's not difficult to see $\frac{x}{e^x} < \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x$ in $[0, \infty)$. Since $\frac{x}{e^x} < 1$ for all $x$ and $\frac{1}{2} < 1$, $(\frac{x}{e^x})^k < (\frac{1}{2})^k$. 

$\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{2})^k$ is a geometric series which converges to $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = 2$. So, we've found the sequence $M_k = (\frac{1}{2})^{k}$ which bounds the function values, which completes the M-test.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That would be a correct response.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Maximize $xe^{-x}$ on $[0,\infty)$. Then write the summand as $(xe^{-x})^k$ and use the $M$-test.